# Chocolatey fails to install visualstudio2017-workload-vctools in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, chocolatey

We have a GitHub Action that uses Chocolatey to install visualstudio2017-workload-vctools to do a Windows build. Here's what the relevant YAML looks like:

```yaml
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Set up GraalVM (Java 11)
        uses: DeLaGuardo/setup-graalvm@8bbfe44ef9c6f5c07e5af036a1bffd561c037d18
        with:
          graalvm-version: '20.3.0.java11'

      - name: Install native-image
        run: gu install native-image
        shell: cmd

      - name: Set up Visual C Build Tools Workload for Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools
        run: |
          choco install visualstudio2017-workload-vctools
      - name: Configure Pagefile
        uses: al-cheb/configure-pagefile-action@v1.2

      - name:
        run: |
          (Get-CimInstance Win32_PageFileUsage).AllocatedBaseSize
```

A few days ago, `choco install visualstudio2017-workload-vctools` started resulting in an error and we've been unable to fix it.

```
visualstudio2017buildtools has been installed.
 The install of visualstudio2017buildtools was successful.
  Software install location not explicitly set, could be in package or
  default install location if installer.

visualstudio2017-workload-vctools v1.3.2 [Approved]
visualstudio2017-workload-vctools package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
ERROR: Unable to detect any supported Visual Studio product. You may try passing --installPath or both --productId and --channelId parameters.
The install of visualstudio2017-workload-vctools was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2017-workload-vctools\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

We tried [pinning the version](https://github.com/okta/okta-cli/pull/89), but that doesn't seem to help.

Full build failure [here](https://github.com/okta/okta-cli/pull/82/checks?check_run_id=2023514838).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround: Use the `windows-2016` image instead of `windows-latest` / `windows-2019` image.

I've also filed a related bug [report](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/2857)

Comment: Hmm... they closed the issue since it was the same image used so likely not a GH Actions problem. Upstream the choco version for `visualstudio2017*` packages were just bumped to 15.9.34.0 a few hours ago (March 10th) so hopefully that addresses it.

https://github.com/jberezanski/ChocolateyPackages/commits/master/visualstudio2017buildtools

Comment: No luck, I also tried the suggestion from the GH issue: `Install-Module -Name VSSetup -Repository PSGallery -Force`

Same results on `windows-2019` next time I have a free moment, I'll grab the logs and create a better issue

Comment: Upstream issue with repo case with logs that jberezanski requested in https://github.com/jberezanski/ChocolateyPackages/issues/97